# Append $ character to a MySQL DB field so that length is increased by 40 %

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to append any character, say `$`, to the name of the `student` field in database such that its length is increased by 40 %, and save the result in the database.

E.g.:

```
Name:  VijayKumar
```

After update:

```
Name:  VijayKumar$$$$
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: What have you done so far? Actually, StackOverflow is not a code writing service - you sould show some of your efforts if you want to get help.

Comment: @GajnathGhule That's not a question, that's a programming assignment. We don't do these, that's *your* job, not ours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `concat()` and `repeat()`:

```
select concat(name, repeat('$', ceil(length(name) * 0.4))
```